# Microsoft Master Data Services (MDS) Migration | 2017 to 2019

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

We're in the process of upgrading our MDS instance, from 2017 to 2019, by means of a migration.  I can't find any good documentation online on how to do this in an efficient way.  Has anyone performed these steps and have some guidance to share?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up getting this to work by backing up the 2016 MDS database and restoring over the MDS database on the 2019 server.  You have to open Master Data Services Configuration Manager after the restore, select the database and choose Upgrade Database (you may get an error about 'clr strict security' which we had to disable).